# Are entity class considered as a model class in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

As in title.

Does the logic model should be placed in entity class?

I want to set value of database related field when object is saving to database.
How can I do that with entity class?

There isn't any save method in entity class in Doctrine 2 so I'm stuck right now.

Could somebody help?

**[EDIT]**

Ok I know I should use [events](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default value of a field when this one is loaded :

```
/**
* @var string $directory
*
* @ORM\Column(name="directory", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $directory = 'src\path\blabla';
```

If you want to set value of a field when this one is saved:

```
/**
* Set directory
*
* @param string $directory
*/
public function setDirectory($directory)
{
    $this->directory = 'src\path\blabla';
}
```

If you want to set value of an empty field when this one is saved:

```
/**
* Set directory
*
* @param string $directory
*/
public function setDirectory($directory ='src\path\blabla' )
{
    $this->directory = $directory;
}
```